# How can I fix this error: "plot: Wrong size for input arguments #2 and #3: Incompatible dimensions."?

Tags: matlab, audio, scilab

I'm trying to plot the image of a notch filter, the frequeny response of the signal before filtering and after the notch's filtering. However I cannot display the two lasts graphs, only the first (Notch). Because that erro: 'plot: Wrong size for input arguments #2 and #3: Incompatible dimensions.'

I tried to change the intervals of the frequency, but doesn't works

```
wavread("C:\Users\kaline\Desktop\Disciplinas\2019.1\PDS\2° etapa\Trabalho final\sirene.wav","size")
[y,Fs,bits]=wavread("C:\Users\kaline\Desktop\Disciplinas\2019.1\PDS\2° etapa\Trabalho final\sirene.wav");Fs,bits


y=loadwave("C:\Users\kaline\Desktop\Disciplinas\2019.1\PDS\2° etapa\Trabalho final\sirene.wav");
//playsnd(y)

fs=12000;
n=[0:5999];
a=[0.940809 -1.105987 0.940809];
b=[1 -1.105987 0.881618];
[xm,fr]=frmag(a,b,512);
subplot(3,1,1)
plot(fr,abs(xm))
Y=fft(y);
f=n*fs/6000;
subplot(3,1,2)
plot(f,abs(Y)),
z=filter(a,b,y);
z=filter(a,b,z);
z=filter(a,b,z);
w=fft(z);
subplot(3,1,3)
plot(f,abs(w),'r')

playsnd(w);
```

I expect the tree plots at the same window and play the audio the filtered audio with playnsd(w);But actually what I have is: only one plot(Notch's graph)

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to change the size of `n` to match the size of `Y`.

Add the following lines of code after `Y=fft(y);` instead of `f=n*fs/6000;`:

```
n_samp = size(Y,2);
n = [0:n_samp-1]
f=n*fs/n_samp;
```

The error is gone, but I am not sure about the correctness of the code (and can't help you with that)...

---

I used stereo sample, so I had to add another minor change.
Here is my code test sample:

```
//wavread("C:\Users\kaline\Desktop\Disciplinas\2019.1\PDS\2° etapa\Trabalho final\sirene.wav","size")
wavread("c:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\toolbox\audio\samples\Turbine-16-44p1-mono-22secs.wav","size")
//[y,Fs,bits]=wavread("C:\Users\kaline\Desktop\Disciplinas\2019.1\PDS\2° etapa\Trabalho final\sirene.wav");Fs,bits
[y,Fs,bits]=wavread("c:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\toolbox\audio\samples\WashingMachine-16-44p1-stereo-10secs.wav");Fs,bits

//y=loadwave("C:\Users\kaline\Desktop\Disciplinas\2019.1\PDS\2° etapa\Trabalho final\sirene.wav");
y=loadwave("c:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\toolbox\audio\samples\Engine-16-44p1-stereo-20sec.wav");
//playsnd(y)

fs=12000;
n=[0:5999];
a=[0.940809 -1.105987 0.940809];
b=[1 -1.105987 0.881618];
[xm,fr]=frmag(a,b,512);
subplot(3,1,1)
plot(fr,abs(xm))
Y=fft(y);
n_samp = size(Y,2);
n = [0:n_samp-1]
f=n*fs/n_samp;
subplot(3,1,2)
plot(f,abs(Y)),
z=filter(a,b,y(1,:));
z=filter(a,b,z(1,:));
z=filter(a,b,z(1,:));
w=fft(z);
subplot(3,1,3)
plot(f,abs(w),'r')

playsnd(w);
```

Comment: Thanks. As you said you helped me with the error, but my code doesn't filter the audio as I expected. The truth is the audio bacame worse to understand.Can I ask you if you can give a feedback how to filter that audio?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with the filtering, I don't have any audio processing experience. I recommend you to post a new question. Try to explain the code a little more (add comments to your code).